# How to pass parameters to another class in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I'm using **Puppet 4** and I'm wondering how I can pass parameters to another class:

I have a custom resource :

```
class system::classA {
  define myresource ($param1, $param2) {
    include system::classB
  }
}

class system::classB {
  file "${param1}"{
    ensure => present
  }
}
```

and I'm calling my resource from another module like

```
system::classA::myresource {
  param1 => "test",
  param2 => "test",
}
```

but the parameters are always empty. How can I pass the parameters or access them in `classB`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameters into *classB* so the data can be passed through:

```
class system::classB($param1, $param2) {
  file { "${param1}":
    ensure => present,
  }
}
```

And then instead of using the `include` function in `system::classA::myresource`, use this style and set the new parameters:

```
define myresource ($param1, $param2) {
  class { "system::classB":
    param1 => $param1,
    param2 => $param2,
  }
}
```

(note that it's unusual to a define *inside* a class, I'd suggest putting `myresource` outside of `classA`.)

Comment: Also note he should be declaring `classB` directly in this case and you may want to mention automatic data bindings as a possibility if he wants to go the `include` route like he is going.

Comment: I do agree with your points, but the question's so lacking in context/heavily obfuscated, it's hard to say for sure how it _should_ be implemented.

Comment: I just think both possibilities should be presented. You prefer the class declaration, and if John answered this he would go the automatic data bindings route. All a matter of opinion there.